# Trying to make a music player for ios but fetch some troubles

Tags: ios, audio-player

Here is my Project Overview ->

I have a viewcontroller(class A) for music list, from there user tap a music and then a url sent to another viewcontroller(class Audioplayer). and Audioplayer class play the song.

code start:

```
- (void) didSelectItem:(ListItem *)item {

    AudioPlayerViewController *apvc = [[AudioPlayerViewController alloc] init];

    apvc.songurl = item.urls;
    [self presentModalViewController:apvc animated:YES];

}
```

code end.

in Audioplayer class have a back button in navigation bar. when back button pressed this code execute

```
-(IBAction)back:(id)sender
{ 
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

Now the problem is I have a "Now Playing" Button In class A Navigation Bar(like iphone Music Apps) and i want to navigate Audioplayer class with all controll in current state by pressing "Now Playing" Button.

Note That i have already try this But it create a new AudioPlayer class object with new controlles.

code is here

```
-(void) Player{ AudioPlayerViewController *audvc = [[AudioPlayerViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:audvc animated:YES completion:nil];}
```

but i want that view that i already dismiss by pressing back Button.

Experts please help Me, if you not understand my problem then please knok me, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Do you mean AudioPlayer or AudioPlayerViewController?

Comment: Any experience with view controllers at all? I cannot see anything related to Audio here? There are plenty of examples for using view controllers around.

Comment: i mean AudioPlayerViewController as audioplayer class gnasher729

Comment: Just a hint for future question: try to summarize your problem in the title. That way the people who might be able to hepl you will actually look at your question. And dont include the request for help in the title - the need is pretty self-explanatory since you are asking a question in the first place :)

Answer (score 0):

This `AudioPlayerViewController` is already created in your storyboard so you shouldn't instantiate it like this.

You could pass the data to your view controller by asking the storyboard to return you a reference to it like this:

```
AudioPlayerViewController *apvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TheVCIdentifier"];

apvc.songurl = item.urls;

//the presentModalViewController method is deprecated.
[self presentViewController:apvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You add the view controller's identifier in `Interface Builder` under the `Identity Inspector > Storyboard ID`.

[image]

Another option would be to create a manual segue with an identifier to your View Controller and implement the `prepareForSegue` method in the View Controller you're transitioning from and implement it like this:

```
- (void) didSelectItem:(ListItem *)item {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YourSegueIdentifier" sender:self];
}
```

and in the `prepareForSegue` method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"YourSegueIdentifier"]) {
       AudioPlayerViewController *apvc = [segue destinationViewController];
       apvc.songurl = item.urls;
    }
}
```

You can check Apple's documentation on this matter [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_storyboard/chapters/StoryboardSegue.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html)